# Trying to ecapsulate CRUD functions for REST API in a custom class, but I keep getting a 403 error even with permissions verified and request header

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

As my title says, I am building a custom class to easily read and update items from a sharepoint list to an ASPX page. Reading is fine, it shows up as expected. But when I try to update a specific list item with a correct value, I get a 403 error. I've doublechecked and my permissions are correct.

Here is my custom class

```
class CRUDManager {
        #baseURL; #evtTarget; #xhr; #mode;
    
        constructor (baseURL){
            var loc = window.location.href;
            this.#baseURL = baseURL == undefined ? baseURL = loc.substring(0, 
            loc.lastIndexOf("/", 
            loc.lastIndexOf("/") - 1) + 1) : baseURL;
            this.#evtTarget = new EventTarget();            
            this.#xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            this.#xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if(this.#xhr.readyState !== 4 || this.#xhr.status !== 200){
                    return;
                };
                switch(this.#mode){
                    case "read":
                        this.#evtTarget.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("onRead", {detail: 
                        JSON.parse(this.#xhr.responseText)}));
                        break;
                    case "update":
                        this.#evtTarget.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("onUpdate", {detail: 
                        JSON.parse(this.#xhr.responseText)}));
                };  
            };
        };
    
        read(name){
            this.#verifyBaseURL();
            this.#mode = "read";        
            this.#xhr.open("GET", `${this.#baseURL}_api/lists/getByTitle('${name}')/items`, true);
            this.#xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
            this.#xhr.send();               
        };
            
        update(name){
            formDigest = ("#_REQUESTDIGEST").value;
            console.log(formDigest);
            this.#verifyBaseURL();
            this.#mode = "update";      
            this.#xhr.open("POST", `${this.#baseURL}_api/lists/getByTitle('${name}')/items(3)`, 
            true);
            this.#xhr.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
            this.#xhr.setRequestHeader("X-RequestDigest","formDigest");
            this.#xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
            this.#xhr.send();               
        };
    
    
    
        addEventListener(evt, func){
                this.#evtTarget.addEventListener(evt, func);
        };
        
        removeEventListener(evt, func){
                this.#evtTarget.addEventListener(evt, func);
        };
            
    };
```

Here is my main javascript on my ASPX page

```
var cm, formDigest;

cm = new CRUDManager();
cm.addEventListener("onUpdate", readHandler);

function onUpdate(evt){
    console.log(evt.details);
};

cm.update("Authors");
```

I am a little unfamiliar with REST API with Sharepoint and could use a nudge in the right direction

Comment: it seems that you're missing the step of including the updated data in your update request to SharePoint. You need to specify the payload containing the updated field values in the request body. Here is the REST API documentation related to list item: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest